# Count the number of unique strings, separated by spaces, in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to count the number of unique strings in a single cell in Excel.

For example, 
"apple pear pear grape"  would be a count of 3
"apple pear grape"  would be a count of 3
"orange orange banana"  would be a count of 2

Any formulas or VBA code that could produce this result?

edit:  I converted the CountUnique sub to a function, which also works

```
Function CountUnique(s As String)
  Dim c As Collection
  Set c = New Collection
  ary = Split(s, " ")
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each a In ary
    c.Add a, CStr(a)
  Next a
  On Error GoTo 0
  CountUnique = c.Count
End Function
```

Comment: I have done some searches on Google but so far I haven't found any formulas that fit this scenario.

Comment: I did find a formula to count words, but not unique words =IF(LEN(TRIM(LV2))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(LV2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LV2," ",""))+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your result using a dictionary :

```
Sub test()
     c = CountDistinct("apple pear pear grape")
End Sub

Public Function CountDistinct(s As String)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim hash As New Dictionary
    For Each x In Split(s, " ")
        hash.Add x, False
    Next

    CountDistinct = hash.Count
End Function
```

Just add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library

Answer (score 2):

Select the cell and run:

```
Sub CountUnique()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    ary = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In ary
        c.Add a, CStr(a)
    Next a
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox c.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: How would you go about range of cells and result of your code being printed in the adjacent cell of each cell in a range?